# How does funcname.varname=value differ from varname=value in Python?

Tags: python, variables, global, declare

In one of my programs ,

```
def travel():
     travel.frate=[]
     travel.s=0
```

in this,the teacher told me to use module name to declare global variables.
like `travel.frate` and `travel.s=0`. She didn't tell why it is so.could some one please explain why we are using this?? She told me to use this because global variables couldn't be declared in my computer.

Comment: but why using function name to declare global variables?? please help

Comment: I've simplified the question to be clearer.

Comment: why do you use the function name to declare global variables?? like its used: travel.s. travel is function name and s is a global variable.why we used this?

Comment: why we used travel before s and not simply s?

Comment: @AanandhiVB, because if it were only `s`, the value would be lost as soon as the function exited. With `travel.s`, the value lives beyond a single call to the function.

Comment: That is to say, you can run `print travel.s` and see the value of `s` even after `travel` is done running, and future calls to `travel()` can see or modify the existing value of `travel.s`, as opposed to starting with a new value.

Answer (score 0):

`travel.s` gives you a variable with identical scope to the function itself -- this is equivalent to a `static` variable in C. This means that the value of `travel.s` isn't deleted from memory as soon as `travel()` exits, as would be the case for `s` defined within the `travel` function.

To state it a little differently, the value persists across multiple calls to the function, unlike a local variable which has a new value assigned each time.

---

By the way -- Python *does* have module-scoped variables (these are what the "global" keyword refers to in Python); your teacher was thus somewhat inaccurate/misleading in the guidance given.

One could use a module-scoped variable like so:

```
s = 0
def travel():
  global s  # this lets the travel function update the value
  s = s + 1 # ...so that the change here persists across multiple calls
```

---

All that said -- use of module-level variables is often a bad practice and a code smell in Python; hopefully, you'll be learning object-oriented design later in your course.